# Hide <g:customCell styleName="width:15%;">

Tags: gwt, hide, cell

I have a customcell in my xml file, It contains vertical panel which I have hide, But it cause some UI design issue as CustomCell is not hidde. Can anyone tell me how I can hide my customcell?. Thanks in advance.

```
<g:customCell styleName="width:15%;" ui:field="parentCell" 
  visible="false">
  <g:VerticalPanel  visible="false" ui:field="SortVPanel"> 
   <g:Grid width="100%">
    <g:row>
      <g:customCell >
        <g:Label styleName="float-left" wordWrap="false" width="65px" > 
            <ui:msg key="lblSort"> Sort By </ui:msg></g:Label>
         </g:customCell>

         <g:customCell styleName="cell-width83">                                        
           <c:ComboBoxComponent  />                                  
         </g:customCell>                                       
     </g:row>
  </g:Grid>
</g:VerticalPanel>
</g:customCell>
```

I want to hide the above customcell, which UiField value is ui:field="parentCell"

Answer (score 1):

The `g:customCell` tag isnt a dom element, but a marker for the `g:Grid` tag to know which items are cells vs rows. This means you can't add html attributes to it. You also can't give it a `ui:field`, since it isn't an object at all.

Instead, you put these on the child Widget which lives inside the `g:customCell` tag, or from your Java code, you can call `grid.getCellFormatter()` and use the methods there to further format the cell which wraps the widget.